# How to compare user id and owner of the file id?

Tags: c, unix, permissions, file-permissions

I'm currently trying to find out how to compare the user id to the actual owner of a file's id to check if the person is the owner. I am attempting to do this like so, but it is not working...

```
struct stat fileStat;
owner = fileStat.st_uid;
if(owner == getuid()){
...
}
```

Doing it this way, the owner id of the file never matches the user id even if I know that the user is in fact the owner of the file. Please help fix my code or provide sample code. Thank you!

Comment: Did you see this with a debugger? or at least, did you attempt printing the values to the console? What are the values? Oh, and, is `owner` a `uid_t`?

Comment: Well I know I own the file because i put it in the server and gave myself all the permissions for it using "chmod 755 program.c". Despite doing this however, the owner of the file id is 59 and the user id is 526718308. Also i'm sorry, but I dont know what a uid_t is or does. I'm sort of learning these concepts as I go.

Comment: What happens if you try this `struct stat stbuf;
    if (stat(__FILE__, &stbuf) == -1)
        return -1;
    fprintf(stdout, "%d, %d\n", stbuf.st_uid, getuid());` what gets printed?

Comment: Sorry I did research and this is a child process so it is a pid_t I believe does that change anything?

Comment: What is a `pid_t`?

Comment: A process id I believe

Comment: Yes I know, but I don't see any `pid_t` in your code.

Comment: Hey I ran what you gave me and it gave this output. 526718303, 526718303

Comment: How are you populating your `fileStat` structure? Also, `chmod` does not change the owner of the file, try `chown` instead. I believe the file is actually not owned by the `getuid()` user.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/YibvD148 here check out my code

Comment: Your code doesn't have a single call to *stat(2)*, I don't understand what your code is trying to do, it's highly unreadable and frankly it doesn't seem like it's your code because you are to lost about it.

Comment: I understand it fine lol. It's just a small part thats messing up. If you don't want to help thats fine.

Comment: Don't take it wrong, I do want to help. But then, can you explain why there is no `stat()` called anywhere? If you want more help write to iharob@gmail.com